# Black holes ejecting out planet-size 'spitballs' against general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon

[This link](https://phys.org/news/2017-01-milky-black-hole-spewing-planet-size.html) says that black holes eject large masses. But according to general relativity not even the light can escape. Is this a violation of the theory?

Comment: No violation.  Black holes are messy eaters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote:

> This link says that black holes eject large masses.

It doesn't say that at all, What it does say is:

> Every few thousand years, an unlucky star wanders too close to the black hole at the center of the Milky Way. The black hole's powerful gravity rips the star apart, sending a long streamer of gas whipping outward. That would seem to be the end of the story, but it's not. New research shows that not only can the gas gather itself into planet-size objects, but those objects then are flung throughout the galaxy in a game of cosmic "spitball."

The 'unlucky' star never actually becomes part of the black hole. So there's no violation of the theory.

Answer (score 2):

No violation, it seems to be all happening outside the event horizon.
The gravitational effects of a black hole extend a good distance beyond the event horizon. 
Some of the matter probably falls to the horizon at some point.